# What frameworks/tools should I use to build a simple single page application with MVC4?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was planning on using the Microsoft Single Page Application project template, but this has been summarily yanked from RC onwards.

I have been asked, yes this is kind of a homework question, to build a simple contacts manager  using MVC3 or above, with absolute minimum whole page requests and maximum use of ajax for UI updates. I was wondering if there was a recommended set of libraries and frameworks I could use? I will be doing all my own coding for this, but I am allowed research etc. I see the SPA apps used Knockout.js. Is there anything else I could/should use?

Comment: JQuery and KnockoutJS are probably all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a no. of options. As mentioned in above answer, backbone.js can be useful. But i must also inform you that there is also another MVVM library called knockout.js which officially comes with mvc4 in VS2012. You can taka look on that.  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Comment: Ya, knockout is looking more attractive for the smaller, more routine type app. Pity MS shelved the SPA project type though.

Answer (score 2):

As your requirement is to build a **Simple Contact Manager**, I highly recommended you use

- [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

incase you only want to use Knockout.js for this, you might want to [read this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5135891/1182982) on SO.

And there is a tutorial series for making a Contact Manager using Backbone.js, see below

[Build a Contacts Manager Using Backbone.js: Part 1](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-1/)

[Build a Contacts Manager Using Backbone.js: Part 2](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-2/)

[Build a Contacts Manager Using Backbone.js: Part 3](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-3/)

[Build a Contacts Manager Using Backbone.js: Part 4](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-4/)

[Build a Contacts Manager Using Backbone.js: Part 5](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-5/)